# cron job on Ubuntu instance doesn't work (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, google-compute-engine

I have been monitoring the functioning of my python (2.7) program which downloads text files from FTP server, parses required information from files and uploads it on Google Cloud Datastore.

This program runs every 10 minutes using cron job on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS instance created on Google Compute Engine. I have added this cron job as root user. (Also created swap space of 1GB).

Instance configuration:
Machine Type: n1-standard-1 (1vCPU, 3.75GB) 
CPU Platform: Intel Sandy Bridge
Disk size: 50GB (Standard Persistent Disk, Mode: Boot, read/write)
Firewalls: Enabled allowing HTTP traffic & Disabled allowing HTTPS traffic

However, after 36 hours, the program is able to download (& parse) some files, while skipping other files.

I have test run this program multiple number of times (runs perfectly fine) and have also referenced other queries on StackOverflow but I am still facing the same issues.

I have been trying this for a long time but I am unable to make any progress on this part. Can someone please help me figure out if I need to make any changes in system configuration or something that I am missing.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think I understand what the issue is. Also, what is the cronjob command exactly?

Comment: `*/10 * * * * cd <path to project folder> && sh init.sh` 
This shell script runs the python program.

Comment: and the issue is what exactly? it's not clear from the description.

Comment: The issue is with downloading latest files from FTP. I am storing the last time when the program ran in `config.ini` file, and gets updated every 10 minutes. I am using SafeConfigParser for read/write in config.ini.

[When logged in]
Program downloads all the latest files from FTP and works completely fine.

[When logged out]
After a day or so, it downloads only some files from FTP and skips other files. The files that are skipped are actually supposed to get downloaded but doesn't happens that way.

Comment: have you tried running as yourself instead of running as root? my suspicion is that some of the paths where you are downloading the files are user-dependant and when you run them out of the cronjob you see them but not as root.

Otherwise, run the `sh init.sh` as root and see if you replicate the behaviour.

Comment: @elelias Yeh thats a good observation. But I have already tried those ways. I ran as root user, self user, gave executable permission to init.sh. Initially I used to run as self user (myself) but I read some articles where people suggested running cronjobs as root. Hence I moved to run programs as root user.

Comment: well, I'm not sure what is happening in your case, kind of hard to tell from here,  but once I had an issue that had to do with the cronjob not having the proper encoding. I wrote `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` at the start of the cronfile and it started working OK.

Also, if you are using a special python version (like Anaconda) it may be the case that your cronjob is taking a different one, as the anaconda path is read from your `$PATH` environmental variable, which will be different in your cronjob

Comment: Made some changes you suggested, and I have been monitoring it till now and I haven't faced any issues. Thanks @elelias.